# The Cacti Draw bad shape

Tags: cisco, network

The Cacti show output in incomplete shape.what is problem?

[image]

Comment: You could really improve your question by providing more details about your problem. Is this happening on all your graphs, or only particular ones? A diagram of the network between the Cacti box and the device you are monitoring and possibly configs could help too.

Comment: This also happens with Observium when the database runs out of connections.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

This happens when Cacti is unable to receive a response from the device being polled.  This could be due to the device not responding (high CPU, bug in SNMP code etc), data being lost between device and Cacti (routing issue, dodgy link etc) or the Cacti box is not able to process the traffic (high CPU, bug etc)